# Properties file not found in classpath when using Tomcat with security manager enabled

Tags: tomcat, classpath, securitymanager

I have a properties my web application needs, but it is not available at package time.  So I put it in TOMCAT_HOME/lib and the application finds it with no problem.  When I run Tomcat with security manager enabled, the file is never found.  I have granted permission to read it, but it is still not found.  I am not getting any security error messages, only that the file is missing.

When Tomcat is run with security manager enabled, is the classpath different?  Is it more restricted?

Comment: How are you trying to load this properties file? A code sample would help.

Comment: I am using the apache-configuration file "PropertiesConfiguration.java".  It takes a single parameter which is the name of the properties file to read from.  It finds this file on the classpath.  PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("myfile.properties");

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  My code was using:

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputFile);

I needed to grant RuntimePermission to get the class loader.

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassloader";
```